# Как организовать данные в игре

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongo

Всем привет, хочу сделать игру "камень, ножницы, бумага". Собираюсь делать, как фуллстак приложение. Собственно сам вопрос, как лучше организовать данные. По задумке на фронте можно будет зарегистрироваться и выбрать сыграть с компьютером или другом. При нажатии сыграть с другом будет два варианта "создать комнату" и "присоединиться". При создании комнаты на беке будет создаваться объект комната. С уникальным id. Но тут я зашёл в тупик. Не знаю, как лучше соединить двух пользователей и записывать результаты игры (будет максимально 5 раундов, при 3 победах одного из игроков игра завершается).
В качестве технологий на беке собираюсь использовать express и graphql, сама база будет на mongo. Понимаю, что graphql тут не нужен, но хочу привыкнуть с ним работать. Буду благодарен советам.

Comment: А нафига тут graphql?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну автор и сказал, что он не нужен :)

Comment: Вам не GraphQL нужен, а WebSocket'ы